# Plotting a step function in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to plot a couple of `UnitStep` functions, but for some
reason, Mathematica won't plot the whole function - Just the top (it doesn't look like a step, more like a line).

How do I tell mathematica to plot it all?

Comment: I found it - You just add "Exclusions -> None" as a plot parameter.

Like this:
Plot[Func[t], {t, 0, 2}, Exclusions -> None]

Thanks anyway

Comment: Glad you were able to find the solution!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An alternative to setting `Exclusions -> None` is to set `ExclusionsStyle -> {style}` if you want to draw the line segments connecting the discontinuities in a different style from the rest of the curve. For example

```
Plot[Round[n], {n, 0, 5}, ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]